# In model-base clustering, can we make prediction for new data?

Tags: clustering

From the EM algorithm it outputs the probabilities of each data belong to each cluster, which are computed from a iterative updating process. So these probabilities are not really theoretical results from the algorithm, in the sense that there is no closed-form expression for them. Then is there no way to deduce the probability of a new data where the covariate vector is different from any current sample used in the model?

If not, how can we make such a prediction using information from the model? It seem not possible since the only things we know are the mean and covariance of each distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There *is* a closed form expression of this. It's just not particularly interesting / useful. It's simply the multivariate Gaussian density, normalized by the sum.

It *can* be used to assign new points to existing clusters.

You simply do the exact same thing you do during EM. You get a probability for each point. That is the assignment of the new point.

Comment: If the "sum" mean the total of all Gaussian densities of all possible combinations of the variables, is it computationally possible? For example if one of the variable is continuous, how can I compute the sum with that?

Comment: Only one combination is needed. As in EM.

Comment: hey just got a really strange situation, so when I try to get the probability of current data and compute their MVN density, EVERYTHING IS ZERO, and I'm pretty sure I have used the right mean and covariance estimates given by the model. I also tried to manually get the value but the exponential part does go to zero... Any idea why this is the case or have I done anything wrong?

Comment: Did you use the inverse?

Comment: I found a possible reason, there's probably some format issue, the function cant evaluate the density correctly unless I took it from the model outputs...that way it actually gives a proper density.